# Firebase query not submitting variables into firebase database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in javascript and I'm creating a contact us form with the help of css and html. I created a function to push the variables (name, email, feedback) to the database but not working . Any help would be appreciated.

This is the button in HTML:

```
<div class="submit">
<button class="button" type="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

And this is the function is JavaScript:

```
function submit() {
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

let ref = firebase.database().ref("feedback");
ref.push({
  FirstName: firstName,
  LastName: lastName,
  Email: emailAddress,
  Feedback: feedback
});

console.log("Feedback sent")
```

}

I can see the "Feedback sent" in the console.

Edit: I also tried this code but it didn't work also :(

```
            function submit() {
            var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
            var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
            var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
            var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

            const database = firebase.database();
            const ref = database.ref('feedback');

            var data = {
                FirstName: firstName,
                LastName: lastName,
                Email: emailAddress,
                Feedback: feedback
            }

            ref.push(data);
        };
```

Comment: Please define "not working". If a push() operation fails, there will be an error message. The `Feedback sent` log doesn't guarantee that the push() operation has succeeded just because it is listed later in the code. Asynchronous operations (anything going to a server or waiting on a UI event) may complete at some time later. Either use async/await on the push operation or add a .then() and .catch() as shown in the samples.

Comment: @Kato I'm a beginner in these two fields. If you may demonstrate how to implement  .then and .catch I will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("feedback");
var newPostRef = ref.push();
newPostRef.set({
  FirstName: firstName,
  LastName: lastName,
  Email: emailAddress,
  Feedback: feedback
}));
```

Comment: is const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName'); a input? if it is then u wanna do this  const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

Answer (score 0):

The `Feedback sent` log doesn't guarantee that the push() operation has succeeded just because it is listed later in the code. Asynchronous operations (anything going to a server or waiting on a UI event) may complete at some time later.

Something like this will give you better starting point:

```
async function submit() {
    const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
    const emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
    const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

    const data = {
      FirstName: firstName,
      LastName: lastName,
      Email: emailAddress,
      Feedback: feedback
    };
    
    let ref = firebase.database().ref("feedback");
    try {
      const res = await ref.push(data);
      console.log("Feedback sent")
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Or with promises if those are more familiar:

```
function submit() {
    const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
    const emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
    const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

    const data = {
      FirstName: firstName,
      LastName: lastName,
      Email: emailAddress,
      Feedback: feedback
    };
    
    let ref = firebase.database().ref("feedback");
    return ref.push(data)
        .then(() => console.log("Feedback sent"))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I'm using a redirect html site from the main index.html btw I'm using the firebase configuration scripts in both files. Any help would be appreciated??

Comment: Btw you seem like an expert and I hope you help me